# Volume Of Revolution Problem

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

The region R is bounded by the graph $$y = -x^2+3x$$ and the $x-axis$ revolved about the line $x=4$. Find the volume.

Answer (score 0):

Our method is Shell. We have: $y = -x^2+3x$, and the $x$ intercepts are: $0,3$, $r = 4-x \to V = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{3} 2\pi(-x^2+3x)(4-x)dx$

If $3x$ was replaced by $2x$, then our analysis becomes: $V = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{2} 2\pi(-x^2+2x)(4-x)dx$

Comment: would this be the same if the problem was the same but the 3x was a 2x?

Comment: can you explain why the shell was more useful then washer?

Comment: You can use the Dishwasher method but you have to find the roots of the equation: $-x^2+3x - y = 0$ in terms of $y$. In fact it takes same amount of time, its like choosing an orange or apple.